# How to use --citeproc instead of pandoc-citeproc in RStudio when bibliography is used in an RMarkdown document?

Tags: r, r-markdown, bibliography, pandoc-citeproc

I get the following error when trying to render a RMarkdown document in RStudio  with bibliography specified in the YAML as `bibliography: references.bib`:

```
[WARNING] Deprecated: pandoc-citeproc filter. Use --citeproc instead.
Error running filter pandoc-citeproc:
Could not find executable pandoc-citeproc
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 83

> rmarkdown::pandoc_version()
[1] ‘2.11.0.4’
```

I cannot find the way to use `--citeproc` instead of `pandoc-citeproc`. Would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be fixed when upgrading the `rmarkdown` package to version 2.5:

https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/releases